# Show that $\int^b_a f^3(x)dx \le ( \int^b_a f(x)dx )^2$ when $f(a)=0$ and $0 \le f'(x) \le 1$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Assume that $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb R$ is a continuously differentiable function. We want to show that $\int^b_a f^3(x)dx \le ( \int^b_a f(x)dx )^2$ if we have $f(a)=0$ and $0 \le f'(x) \le 1$ for all $x \in [a,b]$.

**My attempt:**

I don't know if my approach is correct, but I started by changing the upper limits of the integrals to a variable $y$ so that I can differentiate and obtain $f'$. After changing the upper limits, I want to show

$$( \int^y_a f(x)dx )^2 - \int^y_a f^3(x)dx \ge 0$$

for $y \in [a,b]$. This holds for $y=a$. So I will now show that the derivative of LHS w.r.t. $y$ is positive. That is, I want to show

$$2f(y)(\int^y_a f(x)dx) - f^3(y) \ge 0$$

Again, this holds for $y=a$ since $f(a)=0$. And I take the derivative again and want to show that it is positive. The derivative is

$$2f'(y)(\int^y_a f(x)dx) +2f^2(y)-3f^2(y)f'(y)$$

I couldn't get rid of the integral and I am stuck here. Can you help me by proposing another approach or giving a solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $$F(x)=\left(\int_{a}^{x}f(t)dt\right)^2-\int_{a}^{x}f^{3}(t)dt$$
We have $F(a)=0$,and$$F^{\prime}(x)=2f(x)\int_{a}^{x}f(t)dt-f^{3}(x)=2f(x)\left(\int_{a}^{x}f(t)dt-f^{2}(x)\right)=f(x)G(x)$$
$$f^{\prime}(x)\geqslant0\implies f(x)\geqslant f(a)=0$$
among $G(a)=0,G^{\prime}(x)=2f(x)(1-f^{\prime}(x))\geqslant0$.
Hence$$F(x)\nearrow\implies F(x)\geqslant F(a)\implies F(b)\geqslant0$$